# $C^1$ partially hyperbolic diffeomorphism have Hölder stable holonomies (reference request)

Tags: holonomy, hyperbolic-dynamics, partial-hyperbolicity

I have spent an insane amount of time searching for a preprint I have printed a few months ago but misplaced. I cannot find it anymore and this drives me crazy.

It might not have been meant for publication, or might be more of a survey, I am not sure. I do not remember the authors (obviously) but remember the content: it was notably proved that $C^1$ partially hyperbolic diffeomorphisms have Hölder-continuous stable holonomies. I insist on $C^1$ (I know the $C^2$ case dates back to Pugh, Shub and Wilkinson). The paper also proved absolute continuity of holonomies in $C^{1+\alpha}$ regularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprint I looked for was ["FLAVORS OF PARTIAL HYPERBOLICITY"](http://w3.impa.br/~viana/out/flavors.pdf) by F. Abdenur and M. Viana.